# VB.Net - Properties in HTML attributes

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I'm attempting to insert a base url property into some attributes for a .Net master page that I'm building.

The purpose of this attribute insertion is to make sure that I need only change a single value in a config file to change the head portion of a url, thus saving time when I'm moving my program between different servers.

On the code-behind of the master page I have an exposed property 'baseUrl' that stores the current base location path of the running program.

When I attempt to add my property into a script tag it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# strBaseUrl %>/Javascript/Script.js"></script>
```

This will tend to work with the path changing based on a value I've set elsewhere in config.

However using the property in a similar way for CSS doesn't tend to work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%# strBaseUrl %>/Style/StyleSheets/foundation.min.css">
```

Instead the string appended before the url doesn't reflect the contents of the 'strBaseUrl' variable and just appears as a set of periods and precentage symbols.

Does anyone know a correct means of concatenating the baseUrl into an HTML attribute for this purpose, that works with the link tag (i.e. CSS)?

Comment: If this refuses to cooperate you could just build up the link in code and output it to a literal, that would work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=strBaseUrl%>/Javascript/Script.js"></script>
```